# How to save and retrieve as a list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have class "DilemmData" which I need to save:

```
class DilemmData {
     double percent = 0;
     final String title;
     final String date;
     List<DilemmItemData> plus = [];
     List<DilemmItemData> minus = [];

     DilemmData(
       plus,
       minus, {
       this.percent = 0,
       this.title = '',
       this.date = '',
     });

     static Map<String, dynamic> toJson(DilemmData dilemm) {
       return {
         'percent': dilemm.percent,
         'title': dilemm.title,
         'date': dilemm.date,
         'plus': dilemm.plus.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
         'minus': dilemm.minus.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList(),
       };
     }

     factory DilemmData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       return DilemmData(
         json['plus'],
         json['minus'],
         percent: json['percent'],
         title: json['title'],
         date: json['date'],
       );
     }

     static String encode(List<DilemmData> pressure) => json.encode(
           pressure
              .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((dil) => DilemmData.toJson(dil))
              .toList(),
     );

     static List<DilemmData> decode(String dilemm) =>
         ((json.decode(dilemm) ?? []) as List<dynamic>)
              .map<DilemmData>((dil) => DilemmData.fromJson(dil))
              .toList();
      }

    class DilemmItemData {
        final int importance;
        final String argument;

        DilemmItemData({this.importance = 0, this.argument = ''});

        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
          return {
             'importance': importance,
             'argument': argument,
          };
        }

       factory DilemmItemData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return DilemmItemData(
              importance: json['importance'], argument: json['argument']);
       }
   }
```

Here is my function to get the data:

```
      Future loadDillems() async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

          if (prefs.containsKey('dilemms')) {
             final String data = prefs.getString('dilemms')!;
             MyApp.dilemmList = DilemmData.decode(data);
          }
      }
```

But when I try to get data, I get this exception:

> _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast)**

Answer (score 0):

It shoud be like this

```
MyApp.dilemmList = DilemmData.fromJson(json.decode(data));
```

Comment: For this I need to create a function "decode"?

Comment: sorry I left json by mistake. Edited my answer

Comment: I get this exception: A value of type 'DilemmData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<DilemmData>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<DilemmData>'. If I do as the exception says: MyApp.dilemmList = DilemmData.fromJson(json.decode(data)) as List<DilemmData>;, then I get this exception: _CastError (type 'DilemmData' is not a subtype of type 'List<DilemmData>' in type cast)

Comment: how do you save this value in shared Preferences